# Extent report to be save for future reference

Tags: cucumber, selenium-extent-report

After running the test in Selenium 'Extent report' generate, but would like to know how to save that extent report for future reference.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to generate new report with each run (name like ExtentReport_10_01_2022_09_30_30_30 - ExtentReport_DATE_TIME)
With this approach you will have new report